# A doubt regarding nature of $F(a)$, where $F(a)$ is the intersection of all fields containing field $F$ and element $a$.

Tags: field-theory

Proof in Herstein:
Let us consider elements like $f_{0}+f_{1}a+f_{2}a^{2}+\dots f_{s}a^{s}$. Here $f_{0},f_{1}\dots f_{s}\in F$. Now consider the quotient field $U$ generated by elements like $f_{0}+f_{1}a+f_{2}a^{2}+\dots f_{s}a^{s}$ dividing one another. Proving that this is a field is elementary. 
Also, $U\subset F(a)$ as every field containing $F$ and $a$ has to contain elements like $f_{0}+f_{1}a+f_{2}a^{2}+\dots f_{s}a^{s}$, and $F(a)\subset U$ as $U$ is a field, and $F(a)$ is the smallest field containing $F$ and $a$. Hence $F(a)=U$.

My question is why does $U$ have to be a quotient group? Why can't it simply be the set of all possible $f_{0}+f_{1}a+f_{2}a^{2}+\dots f_{s}a^{s}$? Even in that case, $F(a)=U$!

Comment: What if $1/a$ is not of the form $f_{0}+f_{1}a+f_{2}a^{2}+\dots f_{s}a^{s}$ ... Certainly $1/a \in F(a)$.

Comment: I'd prefer "field of quotients" (field of fractions or the more general [ring of quotients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_quotients)) to quotient field, though the latter is apt to be understood by everyone.  However *not* quotient group, right?

Comment: Yeah, I was going to make the same comment about not using "quotient group." Maybe it's just a typo.

Comment: What book and where of Herstein...?

Comment: @hardmath: Don't know what "apt to be understood by everyone" means, but I certainly did not understand it. For me a quotient field is more likely a quotient of a ring by a maximal ideal, for instance $\Bbb R[X]/(X^2+1)$. Also "dividing one another" is very confusing; in the field of fractions one typically uses a numerator and denominator that are relatively prime or in any case usually _don't_ divide one another.

Comment: @hardmath- I meant "field of quotients". 
DonAntonio- Herstein's "Topics in Algebra"

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen- sorry for the confusion I just meant the field of elements generated by elements like $f_{0}+f_{1}a+f_{2}a^{2}\dots$ dividing one another. And elements like these can divide one another even if they're not relatively prime. If one is a scalar multiple of another, that scalar multiple or its reciprocal will be generated, which again is an element of $F(a)$.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan: My point was that the fraction field contains (amongst others) things like $P/Q$ where neither $P$ divides $Q$ nor $Q$ divides $P$, so these are hardly "elements dividing one another". The point is that in a ring the relation "dividing" already has a meaning, and one that does not agree with its use here.

Comment: Oh, I already spotted the quote (wrongly stated, by the way), in Herstein's "Topics in Algebra", Ed. 1964, page 177: There it says: "...Let U be the set of all such quotients",  which of course has nothing to do with "quotient field" and stuff which, as Marc mention, is something pretty different.

Answer (score 2):

OK, well consider the quotient field $F(x)$ of polynomials over $F$.

Certainly $x$ is an element of the field, but just polynomials in $x$ generate $F[x]\subsetneq F(x)$. The same can be said about any $a$ which isn't algebraic over $F$.

On the other hand, if $a$ is algebraic over $F$ with minimal polynomial degree $n$, then $F[a]=F(a)$, and in that case, the polynomials over $a$ are already a field.

Answer (score 1):

$U$ has to be the quotient field because otherwise it wouldn't be a field. If it simply contained elements of the form $f_0+f_1a+f_2a^2+\cdots+f_sa^s$, then it wouldn't necessarily contain $a^{-1}$ (for example).

Comment: True. Sorry. Stupid question. Don't know how I missed that. I was obsessing only with the reciprocals of $f_{0},f_{1},f_{2}\dots$, which would be contained in $F$. Sorry.

Comment: *Sometimes* the polynomials alone contain $a^{-1}$!

Comment: @rschwieb I interpreted the question as having $a$ be an indeterminant over $F$, but if you'd like I'll add the word "necessarily".

Comment: @AlexBecker Sure, that fixes things :)

Comment: @AlexBecker- I read something in Herstein right now which might be of some interest to you. Let $p(x)\in F[x]$ such that $p(a)=0$. Let $p(x)$ be of the form $f_{0}+f_{1}a+f_{2}a^{2}\dots f_{s}a^{s}$, where $f_{0}\neq 0$. Hence, $(x,p(x))=1$. This implies that there are polynomials $t(x)$ and $r(x)$ such that $p(x).t(x)+x.r(x)=1$. This in turn implies $p(a).t(a)+a.r(a)=1$. $p(a)=0$. Hence, $a.r(a)=1$. $r(a)$ is hence the inverse of $a$!!

Comment: I suppose I was right. The set of all such polynomials is indeed a field, as the multiplicative inverses of all non-zero polynomials are contained within the set (all polynomials co-prime with p(a) are no-zero).

Comment: @AyushKhaitan Yes, I quite familiar with this. I simply misunderstood your question as assuming $a$ was an indeterminant, so satisfied no such polynomial $p$.

Comment: @AyushKhaitan You are right iff $a$ satisfies some polynomial over $F$.

Comment: @AlexBecker- I might be wrong, but wouldn't $a$ always satisfy a polynomial? If we're considering polynomials of the form $f_{0}+f_{1}a+f_{2}a^{2}\dots$, a simple $f_{1}=1, f_{k}=0_{k\neq 1}$ would form such a polynomial!

Comment: @AyushKhaitan That's not what it means to satisfy a polynomial. When I say $a$ satisfies a polynomial over $F$, I mean there is some $p(x)\in F[x]$ such that $p(a)=0$.

Comment: Oh you mean if $a$ is algebraic over $F$. Yes you're right, that is indeed a non-trivial condition.